# A slide animation in between widgets

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

I am working on an application where i need to show animation on a screen.I did few things but the desired out put is not what I am exactly looking for. I am attaching image and prototype link for the animation.
Basically I want to tap on catgeory and show the animation to move the respective category color from selected category to tapped category and also want to move the content to appear from left or right.

[Animation prototype link](https://www.figma.com/proto/Z5Ayuuf2b5uul5vS18XFTT/Swapp-Mobile-App---FOR-DEV?type=design&node-id=1376-4962&t=zTIqCgu6w0oj9hPv-0&scaling=min-zoom&page-id=1345%3A4461&starting-point-node-id=1376%3A4962)

```
Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: VisitCardCategory.values
                            .map((e) => AnimatedBuilder(
                                animation: _animationController,
                                builder: (context, child) {
                                  return SlideTransition(
                                    position: Tween<Offset>(
                                      begin: Offset(
                                          _animationController.value, 0.0),
                                      end: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                                    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
                                        parent: _animationController,
                                        curve: Curves.easeIn)),
                                    child: FilterWidget(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        filterByCategory(category: e);
                                      },
                                      category: e,
                                      selectedColor: e == selectedCategory
                                          ? e.color
                                          : Colors.white,
                                      controller: _animationController,
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }))
                            .toList()),
```

Answer (score 0):

First step to achiever this would be to create the tabs in Row :

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          _SwapButton(0, 'First Page'),
          _SwapButton(1, 'Second Page'),
          _SwapButton(2, 'Third Page'),
          _SwapButton(3, 'Fourth Page'),
          _SwapButton(4, 'Fifth Page'),
        ],
      ),
```

Now you would make the page view :

```
Expanded(
        child: PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          onPageChanged: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentPageIndex = index;
            });
          },
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Text('Content for Tab 1'),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text('Content for Tab 2'),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text('Content for Tab 3'),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text('Content for Tab 4'),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text('Content for Tab 5'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Now you would create the widget that would make the animation work :

```
Widget _SwapButton(int index, String label) {
return ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    _pageController.animateToPage(
      index,
     //This is for the sliding effect to make the data slide between tabs
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  },
  style: ButtonStyle(
  //Style button as you want 
    ),
  ),
  //add label to button
  child: Text(label),
);
 }
```

Hope this helps you achieve what u want ! if worked do check the correct answer mark!

Reference Link : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController/animateToPage.html

Comment: Thank for the reply the solution you provided doesn't work for my use case. If you look closely to the prototype   I want the animation on category when tapping on it.